# php Mysql return information from the grand children tree

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql database called retail. it has two tables .1) users 2) sales
table 1) users contains information about agents and buyers. all buyer must have a parent(his agent) also all agents have their own parent agents. agent and buyer is separated by 'agent' value. value 0 means its a buyer and agent '1' means agent. all agent must have their commission based on their child(buyer, agent) sales.

For example in this database user id john (1) having total of 21 child accounts including his own 1 (user id = 21) buyer account

every purchase done by any buyer , that sales credit or commission will go through all his parent resellers one by one

for example

user id 19(a buyer account) purchased something. then this sales credits or commission will get to all agents related to his account based on parent relation

in this case user id 19
19's parent is 10
10's parent is 8
8's parent is 3
3's parent is 1

so this sale's credits will have no agent 10,8,3,1

My requirement is simply list sales based on agent user id without showing the full agent tree for example i want to list agent id 1's sales

then it should list like this
agent 1)
sales
product_id ==> 21
amount ==> 33
agent ==>3 (please note this is showing only agent 3 which is directly on his user id 1's under, but this sales have done by one of his end tree buyer)

Hope you people understand the scenario.
i am using php for application side coding. Thanks in advance. Please note the below database structure and sample data

```html
mysql> select * from users;
+----+--------+-------+-----------+
| id | Name   | Agent | Parent_id |
+----+--------+-------+-----------+
|  1 | john   |     1 |        -1 |
|  2 | anil   |     1 |         1 |
|  3 | sam    |     1 |         1 |
|  4 | peter  |     1 |         2 |
|  5 | sara   |     1 |         1 |
|  6 | tony   |     0 |         3 |
|  7 | suresh |     0 |         5 |
|  8 | kapil  |     1 |         3 |
|  9 | dhanya |     0 |         2 |
| 10 | sharma |     1 |         8 |
| 11 | das    |     0 |         8 |
| 12 | diya   |     0 |         4 |
| 13 | hani   |     1 |         4 |
| 14 | jane   |     0 |        10 |
| 15 | deva   |     1 |         8 |
| 16 | elma   |     0 |        13 |
| 17 | raj    |     1 |        10 |
| 18 | manu   |     0 |         5 |
| 19 | gopi   |     0 |        10 |
| 20 | pavi   |     1 |         2 |
+----+--------+-------+-----------+
```

Now sales table

```html
mysql> select * from sales;
+----+------------+--------+---------------+
| id | product_id | amount | buyer_user_id |
+----+------------+--------+---------------+
|  1 |         10 |     25 |             6 |
|  2 |         11 |     31 |             7 |
|  3 |         17 |     12 |             9 |
|  4 |         10 |     25 |            11 |
|  5 |         13 |     17 |            12 |
|  6 |         17 |     12 |            14 |
|  7 |         10 |     25 |            16 |
|  8 |         17 |     12 |            18 |
|  9 |         21 |     33 |            19 |
| 10 |         17 |     12 |            11 |
| 11 |         13 |     17 |             7 |
| 12 |         10 |     25 |            21 |
| 13 |         17 |     12 |            22 |
+----+------------+--------+---------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You should find the buyer user ID first-

```
select `buyer_user_id` from `sales`;
```

Let save the `buyer_user_id` in a php variable- $buyer_user_id

Now find the detail of first buyer user ID with PHP and MySQL-

```
select * from users where `id` = $buyer_user_id;
//Now in PHP
$user_id=$buyer_user_id;
```

Then make a while loop using PHP with this query to find all parents-

```
select * from users where `Parent_id` = $user_id;
//Print the detail with PHP and the ending condition is ->> $user_id!=-1
```

I think, you have your answer.

Comment: This query will help to find one level Up agents only.

Comment: while($clientID = 17) {
    $qrystr = "SELECT Parent_id FROM users WHERE id = '$clientID' ";
 $qry = mysql_query($qrystr);
 $details = mysql_fetch_array($qry);
 $clientID = $details['Parent_id'];
 }